# Phonegap open android files

Tags: android, cordova, adt, cordova-3

I can't seem to figure out how to open up my android phonegap project in eclipse. I need todo this because I need to customize some android settings and files specifally to install facebook connect on phonegap 3.0.0. The app runs fine on my emulator, but the problem is that I can't find the local android files to open in eclipse. With ios its easy, you go into `platforms/ios/projectname.xcodeproj` and it opens your ios build in xcode. With android, it's nothing like this. I'm using this tutorial btw: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/3.0

Comment: one of the thigns I need to do is import Facebooks Android SDK into eclipse, which I cannot do if I can't open the android project files in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android Platform Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) has instructions on how you can use an IDE (eclipse) with Cordova 3.0.0 and the command line:

Use the command line to set up the new project:

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
$ cd hello
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova build
```

After that, open up Eclipse, select "New Project", hit "Android Project from Existing Code", and navigate to the `hello/platforms/android` folder that was created. This should load the project into your Eclipse workspace and you should be able to edit the Android files just like in the pre-3.0.0 days.